# What is class as opposed to Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: c++, class, oop

sorry to bother but I'm a newbie programmer and has just been starting on c++ course. The reason I asked this question is because I've been hearing on OOP and its relation to class.

So my question is: 
Does class actually simplify the programming code just because it groups up all related functions into one single "object" thats called "class" ?

One more thing is that... 
Why do we create class inheritance when we could use one class and derive all functions from that one class alone?

Sorry to bother.

Newbie programmer.

Comment: To truely make you comprehend, it would require us to write at least a week to produce a nearly good enough answer. Just follow along with your c++ studies, read books, look how other people use it. There is no need for you to doubt OOP. It is a widely used and loved idiom, and you will understand why soon enough, if you just continue ;)

Comment: Useful link from answer that was deleted [OOP in C++](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp3_OOP.html)

Answer (score 1):

> *"Does class actually simplify the programming code just because it groups up all related functions into one single "object" thats called "class" ?"*

The main idea is to encapsulate *state* (== data) with operations that can be applied to it into a single *class type*.

Yes, that simplifies programming code, because there are certain interfaces/operations that can be used with this type.

> *"Why do we create class inheritance when we could use one class and derive all functions from that one class alone?"*

Derived classes may introduce different behavior as inherited from their base class. There are many uses when you want to change that behavior, without inventing new function names all the time (or just add numbers to them).